# print the value of child node in firebase swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, firebase

[image: this is my JSON]

using singleEventOfType method i can print the value of email or other childs of a logged in user.. but when a logged in user searches another user with email i want all the details of that searched user and display in label on a view controller.. for it i made a userList containing info as :

UserList:

- simplelogin1: aaa@gmail.com
- simplelogin4: lll@gmail.com

now when the logged in user searches for another user by email .. then how do i use that email to iterate in the UserList path and get me the childKey for that particular email.. so i could than use that childKey to get the other info of the searched user and display on a view controller. what should i write in the

```
ref.observeEventOfSingleType
```

please help i m new to firebase and swift! thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [search a user with email in firebase swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32522079/search-a-user-with-email-in-firebase-swift)

Comment: i have deleted that question . asked the same thing here but with some more information,do u have an answer to this question?

Comment: Next time, don't **delete** a question but **edit** it. If I already had an answer, I would write it as an answer below. My comments are an effort to show you how to make it easier for people to help you. You still include the JSON as a picture, instead of in a code block as I asked in your previous question. That means that in order to help you, someone will have to manually type your JSON into a Firebase database.